# ionic2: how to fit 3 cards to screen?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using Ionic2 and I want to make design like that:[image]

I made the cart but I can't make the position as image 
this is card code:

```
<ion-grid>
        <ion-row wrap>
            <ion-col width-50>
                <ion-card>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-icon name="start" item-start></ion-icon>
                        <ion-icon name="ios-heart-outline" item-end></ion-icon>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-card-content text-center>
                        <ion-item text-center>
                            <img src="http://safe-pay.co/safepay/public/uploadedimg/user/avatar.png" style="width:40px;height:40px" />
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            <span>Canon Power <br/>shot SX60 HS</span>
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            <span id="oldPrice">119.900KD</span>
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            <span id="newPrice">100.900KD</span>
                        </ion-item>
                        <ion-item>
                            <ion-rating [numStars]="5" [readOnly]="false" [value]="3" (clicked)="starClicked($event)">
                            </ion-rating>
                        </ion-item>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
     </ion-grid>
```

this is the output[image]

can any one tell me the how to position them

Comment: Can you also show the output of your HTML?

Comment: @RaxWeber I edited the post now

Comment: Could you make a plunker using embed.plnkr.co/puyuJKjb1CATwTdtpsIV ?

Answer (score 0):

try putting style to make it aligned as you want ..

```
<div style="width:100%;float:left;">

<ion-card style="width:33.33%;float:left;"> 
   <ion-card-content text-center>
           SAMLE1
   </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<ion-card style="width:33.33%;float:left;"> 
   <ion-card-content text-center>
           SAMLE2
   </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

<ion-card style="width:33.33%;float:left;"> 
   <ion-card-content text-center>
           SAMLE3
   </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

</div>
```